# Powershell Convertto-HTML from list items also outputs raw objects before the actual HTML

Tags: csom, powershell-script

I am writing a Powershell Script to read SPListItems, create a PSObject for each, add it to the PS Array and after the loop ends I use the following to convertto-html

```
myArray | convertto-html -path ......
```

Part of my code within iterating the list items is as follows:

```
$obj = new-object PSOBject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Title" -Value $item["Title"] |Out-Null
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $file.Name |Out-Null
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Link" -Value $file.ServerRelativeUrl |Out-Null

$myArray += $obj
```

The problem is that I do get the HTML. However, I also get raw psobjects. The Html generated is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
System.Collections.Hashtable
System.Collections.Hashtable
System.Collections.Hashtable
System.Collections.Hashtable

<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>IsReadOnly</th><th>IsFixedSize</th><th>IsSynchronized</th><th>Keys</th><th>Values</th> 
<th>SyncRoot</th><th>Count</th></tr>
<tr><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection</td> 
<td>System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection</td><td>System.Object</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection</td> 
<td>System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection</td><td>System.Object</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection</td> 
<td>System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection</td><td>System.Object</td><td>2</td></tr>

</table>
</body></html>
```

Other than using html string to concatenate a html document, can someone please help me fix it using Convertto-Html?

Thank you.

Comment: how do you initialize $myArray before you start adding objects to it?

Comment: can you post your entire `myArray | convertto-html` command?

Comment: ----- $myArray = @()

Comment: it was not letting me add without the leading dashes. Therefore, added some - otherwise actual declaration starts from the $

Comment: $myArray | ConvertTo-Html -head $Header    | out-file "c:\temp\htmldoc.html" -Force 



$Header is just a here-string with <style> tag to add some css to the output

Comment: You are only adding three values to the objects in your array (Title, Name, and Link), but in the generated html contains column headers `<th>IsReadOnly</th><th>IsFixedSize</th><th>IsSynchronized</th><th>Keys</th><th>Values</th> 
<th>SyncRoot</th><th>Count</th>`.  When I copy the code you've given, my generated html column headers are `<th>Title</th><th>Name</th><th>Link</th>` -- is there some additional code you haven't posted? are you sure you are not modifying the array in some way before calling convert?

Comment: The problem is not those column headers - I modified some stuff before pasting the code here for privacy reasons. The problem is those additional "System.Collections.Hashtable" output being generated at the top

Comment: I understand that the problem is with the extra objects getting injected into your html.  What I am telling you is that the code that you have posted here does not cause that.  I have executed the code you have posted and it does not cause that behavior.  Therefore, the problem must be in the code that you have not posted here.

Comment: "Once you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be true." -- Doyle

Comment: I see, ok. For some weird reason when I run the code again, it is working fine now. Wonder what had caused it to output that initially

Comment: This is indeed very strange. When i re-execute it (without any changes at all), the output is correct. Thanks for taking the time to run it though, really appreciate it.